# Why does style get out of order when zooming-in?

Tags: html, css

When I zoom-out on my website everything works fine and stays fixed in it's place without errors, however when I zoom-in above the 100% mark on my computer, some of my content that isn't centered by default will move to the right and will loose it's alignment with the content that is fixed in it's place. I have tried to approach this in lot's of ways but I never managed to get things right.

Ok so here is what happens when my website is zoomed out and what happens once zoomed in (Notice how the photo and the image providing a link are moved to the right when zoomed in): http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480700334/zoom_out_1_xvl0vx.jpg
http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480700334/zoom_in_1_syodzh.jpg

And the same happens in other sections of my webpage which are commented in my code...

And here is my Code:

```css
/*This is the start of section 3 stylsheet. At first glance everything works fine
But I'll soon point out where my problems start...'*/
section.sec3{
 background-color: #232323;
 width:100%;
 padding: 120px 0 10px 0;
}

.separador{
 width: 150px;
 height: 20px;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

section.sec3 h4{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}


/*Okay what I've done with this property ".conteudo" was that when you zoom-out everything will stay locked in place, however it won't work when you zoom-in, in the browser above the 100% mark, and everything will move to the right instead of being aligned with the rest of my content*/
.conteudo
 {
  align-content: center;
 }

div.conteudo{
 width: 1500px;
 margin: auto;
}
 
section.sec3 img.foto_perfil{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 297px;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

section.sec3 p{
 margin-top: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Lato'; 
}

section.sec3 p.p_2_sec3{
 font-weight: bold;
}
/**/

/*This part right here is just for reference and it works as intended, so just ignore it*/
section.sec3 img.oqueseifazer{
 display: block;
 margin: auto; 
 margin-top: 50px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 width: 930px;
 height: 27px;
}

section.sec3  div.posicao_horizontal2{
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

section.sec3  div#img2{
 display: inline-block;
}

section.sec3 div img.img1{
 margin-right: 40px;
}

section.sec3 div img.img1{
 margin-left: 28px;
}

section.sec3 div img.img3{
 margin-left: 40px;
}

section.sec3 div img.img4{
 margin-left: 40px;
}
/**/

/*Okay once again the same problem happens with my image that provides a link, wich moves to the right when you zoom-in above the 100% mark*/
.conteudo2
 {
  align-content: center;
 }

div.conteudo2{
 width: 1500px;
 margin: auto;
}
 
section.sec3 img.linkpdf{
 display: block;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 297px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
/**/
/*Ignore this part, it's just for reference*/
section.sec4{
 padding: 120px 0 400px 0;
 background-color: #f7f5f5;
}

section.sec4 h5{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}

section.sec4  div.posicao_horizontal2{
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

section.sec4  div#img3{
 display: inline-block;
}

section.sec4 div img.img1{
 width: 301px;
 height: 741px;
}

section.sec4 div img.img2{
 margin-left: 40px;
 width: 301px;
 height: 741px;
}

section.sec4 div img.img3{
 margin-left: 40px;
 width: 301px;
 height: 741px;
}

section.sec4 img.pers_negocio{
 display: block;
 margin: auto; 
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 1022px;
 height: 60px;
}
/*Again I resorted to use the "align-content" property, wich solved my problem when zooming out but won't work when zooming-in and once zoomed-in the whole thing will move to the right and won't stay aligned with the rest of the content*/
.conteudo3
 {
  align-content: center;
 }

div.conteudo3{
 width: 1500px;
 margin: auto;
}

section.sec4  div.outros_elementos{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

section.sec4 div.negocios_extra{
 float: left; 
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 50px
}


section.sec4 div p.title_sec4{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #ffa31a;
 font-size: 22px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

section.sec4 div  p{
 margin-top: 10px; 
 margin-left: 238px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'DIN Alt', Fallback, sans-serif;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

section.sec4  div#img4{
 display: inline-block; 
}

section.sec4 img.negocio_ilustracao{
 margin-right: 20px;
 width: 271px;
 display: block;
 height: 303px;
}

section.sec4 img.negocio_webdesign{
 width: 271px;
 display: block;
 height: 303px;
}
/**/
/*This is last part where my problem happens in my website, this time I have a div containg onlly text and a button instead of images as the sections I've shown before, I am almost sure there is some property I should be using for my div's but I can't figure out what... */
/*same as before just ignore the begining of the section*/
section.sec5{
 background-color: #fcb732;
 background-image: url("images/az-subtle.png");
 padding: 120px 0 290px 0;
}

section.sec5 h6{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -55px;
}

section.sec5 p.intro_contact{
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}
/**/
/*Here starts the problem*/
section.sec5 h2{
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 22px;
}

section.sec5 p.par_contact{
 margin-top: 15px;
 font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Fallback, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
}

section.sec5 p.email{
 margin-top: 15px;
 font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Fallback, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #563715;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }

section.sec5 div#wrapper{
 margin-left: 290px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

/*I created conteudo 4 to reinforce the centering of sec5 but maybe it's better to remove it since when it is removed the whole thing will look the same (but will still have the same issue of the other sections) */

.conteudo4{
 align-content: center;
}

div.conteudo4{
 width: 1217px;
 margin: auto;
}

section.sec5  div.inquerito_contactos{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

section.sec5 div.info_contactos{
 float: left; 
 margin-left: 20px;

}

.button {
    background-color: #563715;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec3">
 <h4> O Meu Trabalho </h4>
 <img class="separador" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693261/separador_de_titulo_branco_s5kkqx.png">
 <div class="conteudo">
 <img class="foto_perfil" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693261/foto_perfil_hb5oao.jpg">
  <p> Sempre tive o gosto em tornar as coisas que me rodeiam melhores. <br>
  Desde que efetuei o meu curso de Profissional de Multimédia, já <br>
  disponibilizei os  meus serviços como: </p>
  <p class="p_2_sec3"> + Estagiário em Leça de Palmeira na empresa "Wonder Dimension" 2 <br>
  meses e uma semana;<br>
  + Técnico de Multimédia desde 2015 na empresa "Tecla Virtual" em Gaia. </p>
  <p> Os meus projectos já permitiram facultar imagem corporativa a <br> 
  algumas empresas em inicialização e já conto com um reportório, embora <br>
  ainda modesto, dos meus trabalhos onde já criei: logótipos, cartazes, <br>
  flyers, capas, cartões de visita, banners...<br>
  Quando não estou a trabalhar gosto de aprender a tocar guitarra, ver <br>
  filmes, ler livros, ouvir musica, ficar informado e estar com a família. </p>
 </div>
  <!--Everything contained in this part works as intended since everything is centered and locked into place, I won't even put the images uploaded here since this part is just for reference-->
 <img class="oqueseifazer" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480694125/sparador_o_que_sei_fazer_lkypxq.png">
 <div class="posicao_horizontal2">
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img1" src="images/ilustrator.png"> </div>
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img2" src="images/photoshop.png"> </div>
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img3" src="images/dreamweaver.png"> </div>
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img4" src="images/flash.png"> </div>
 </div>
 <!---->
 <!--Here is when things get messy again once you zoom in above the 100% mark in the browser-->
 <div class="conteudo2">
 <img class="linkpdf" usemap="#linkpdfmap" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693261/link_portfolio_tnpxws.png
">
  <map name="linkpdfmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="255,35,302,84" href="portfolio/portfolio.pdf" target="_blank">
  </map>
 </div> 
</section>
<!---->

<!--Ignore the beginning of this section since it's just for reference-->
<section class="sec4">
 <h5> Propostas de Negocio </h5>
 <img class="separador" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/separador_de_titulo_preto_co4ztz.png
">
 <div class="posicao_horizontal2">
  <div id="img3"> <img class="img1" src="images/oferta_de_negocio_1.png"> </div>
  <div id="img3"> <img class="img2" src="images/oferta_de_negocio_2.png"> </div>
  <div id="img3"> <img class="img3" src="images/oferta_de_negocio_3.png"> </div>
 </div>
 <img class="pers_negocio" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/personalize_o_seu_negocio_cmv8ia.png">
<!---->
 <!--Once again this part works when you zoom out, but will move to the right once you zoom-in above the 100% mark-->
 <div class="conteudo3">
  <div class="outros_elementos">
   <p class="title_sec4"> Precisa <br>
   de outros elementos? </p>
   <p> Contacte-nos e conheça os  vários <br>
   preços e outras soluções diversas. </p>
   <p> Quer seja no complemento do seu <br>
   pack ou á parte, a Multimedia <br>
   House dispõe de um amplo serviço <br>
   de design gráfico e webdesign que <br>
   coloca ao seu dispor. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="negocios_extra">
  <div id="img4"> <img class="negocio_ilustracao" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/negocio_ilustracao_design_d4s5fi.png"> </div>
  <div id="img4"> <img class="negocio_webdesign" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/negocio_webdesign_fhe6nk.png"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </section>
<!---->
<!--Ignore the beginning since it's just for reference-->
<section class="sec5">
 <h6> Vamos Trabalhar? </h6>
 <img class="separador" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/separador_de_titulo_preto_co4ztz.png">
  <p class="intro_contact"> Estou actualmente dísponível para projectos freelance.<br>
 Se estiver interessado em trabalhar comigo, por favor entre em contacto através dos métodos<br>
 abaixo referidos.</p>
 <!---->
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div class="conteudo4">
  <div class="inquerito_contactos"> 
  <h2> Tem um projecto em mente ? </h2>
  <p class="par_contact"> Tire um minuto do seu tempo e responda<br>
  a um inquérito acerca do seu projecto.<br><br>
  Após responder o inquérito, entrarei em<br>
  contacto consigo o mais brevemente<br>
  possível.<br>
  </p>
  <a target="_blank" href="typeform_multimedia_house.html" class="button"> Inquérito</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info_contactos">
  <h2> Entre em contacto comigo !</h2>
  <p class="par_contact"> Luís Henriques </p>
  <p class="par_contact"> Vila Nova de Gaia | 4400-008 </p>
  <p class="par_contact"> +351 915 974 285 </p>
  <a href="mailto:luishenriques96@gmail.com"><p class="email"> luishenriques96@gmail.com </p></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you zoom in, the page will behave as if you are looking at it in the smaller screen. Your media queries are kicking in the zoom_in_1.

Comment: You can always do a search. If you know how to keyword your problem, you will find answers. This is what I put in the keyword "browser zoom and media queries", and found bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got two things causing the problem.

The `.conteudo` is making that container 1500px wide and `.foto_perfil` is setting a margin-left of 297px. As you zoom in those just get too big and they go off the screen.

Instead. Change the width of `.conteudo` to something like width:80% and remove the left margin from the photo.

```css
/*This is the start of section 3 stylsheet. At first glance everything works fine
But I'll soon point out where my problems start...'*/
section.sec3{
 background-color: #232323;
 width:100%;
 padding: 120px 0 10px 0;
}

.separador{
 width: 150px;
 height: 20px;
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

section.sec3 h4{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}


/*Okay what I've done with this property ".conteudo" was that when you zoom-out everything will stay locked in place, however it won't work when you zoom-in, in the browser above the 100% mark, and everything will move to the right instead of being aligned with the rest of my content*/
.conteudo
 {
  align-content: center;
 }

div.conteudo{
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
}
 
section.sec3 img.foto_perfil{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

section.sec3 p{
 margin-top: 50px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: 'Lato'; 
}

section.sec3 p.p_2_sec3{
 font-weight: bold;
}
/**/

/*This part right here is just for reference and it works as intended, so just ignore it*/
section.sec3 img.oqueseifazer{
 display: block;
 margin: auto; 
 margin-top: 50px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 width: 930px;
 height: 27px;
}

section.sec3  div.posicao_horizontal2{
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

section.sec3  div#img2{
 display: inline-block;
}

section.sec3 div img.img1{
 margin-right: 40px;
}

section.sec3 div img.img1{
 margin-left: 28px;
}

section.sec3 div img.img3{
 margin-left: 40px;
}

section.sec3 div img.img4{
 margin-left: 40px;
}
/**/

/*Okay once again the same problem happens with my image that provides a link, wich moves to the right when you zoom-in above the 100% mark*/
.conteudo2
 {
  align-content: center;
 }

div.conteudo2{
 width: 1500px;
 margin: auto;
}
 
section.sec3 img.linkpdf{
 display: block;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 297px;
 width: 600px;
 height: 85px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
/**/
/*Ignore this part, it's just for reference*/
section.sec4{
 padding: 120px 0 400px 0;
}

section.sec4 h5{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -50px;
}

section.sec4  div.posicao_horizontal2{
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

section.sec4  div#img3{
 display: inline-block;
}

section.sec4 div img.img1{
 width: 301px;
 height: 741px;
}

section.sec4 div img.img2{
 margin-left: 40px;
 width: 301px;
 height: 741px;
}

section.sec4 div img.img3{
 margin-left: 40px;
 width: 301px;
 height: 741px;
}

section.sec4 img.pers_negocio{
 display: block;
 margin: auto; 
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 1022px;
 height: 60px;
}
/*Again I resorted to use the "align-content" property, wich solved my problem when zooming out but won't work when zooming-in and once zoomed-in the whole thing will move to the right and won't stay aligned with the rest of the content*/
.conteudo3
 {
  align-content: center;
 }

div.conteudo3{
 width: 1500px;
 margin: auto;
}

section.sec4  div.outros_elementos{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

section.sec4 div.negocios_extra{
 float: left; 
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 50px
}


section.sec4 div p.title_sec4{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #ffa31a;
 font-size: 22px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

section.sec4 div  p{
 margin-top: 10px; 
 margin-left: 238px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: 'DIN Alt', Fallback, sans-serif;
 margin-right: 50px;
}

section.sec4  div#img4{
 display: inline-block; 
}

section.sec4 img.negocio_ilustracao{
 margin-right: 20px;
 width: 271px;
 display: block;
 height: 303px;
}

section.sec4 img.negocio_webdesign{
 width: 271px;
 display: block;
 height: 303px;
}
/**/
/*This is last part where my problem happens in my website, this time I have a div containg onlly text and a button instead of images as the sections I've shown before, I am almost sure there is some property I should be using for my div's but I can't figure out what... */
/*same as before just ignore the begining of the section*/
section.sec5{
 background-color: #fcb732;
 background-image: url("images/az-subtle.png");
 padding: 120px 0 290px 0;
}

section.sec5 h6{
 font-family: 'Playfair Display';
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -55px;
}

section.sec5 p.intro_contact{
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}
/**/
/*Here starts the problem*/
section.sec5 h2{
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 22px;
}

section.sec5 p.par_contact{
 margin-top: 15px;
 font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Fallback, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
}

section.sec5 p.email{
 margin-top: 15px;
 font-family: 'Liberation Sans', Fallback, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #563715;
 text-decoration: underline;
 }

section.sec5 div#wrapper{
 margin-left: 290px;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

/*I created conteudo 4 to reinforce the centering of sec5 but maybe it's better to remove it since when it is removed the whole thing will look the same (but will still have the same issue of the other sections) */

.conteudo4{
 align-content: center;
}

div.conteudo4{
 width: 1217px;
 margin: auto;
}

section.sec5  div.inquerito_contactos{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

section.sec5 div.info_contactos{
 float: left; 
 margin-left: 20px;

}

.button {
    background-color: #563715;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec3">
 <h4> O Meu Trabalho </h4>
 <img class="separador" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693261/separador_de_titulo_branco_s5kkqx.png">
 <div class="conteudo">
 <img class="foto_perfil" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693261/foto_perfil_hb5oao.jpg">
  <p> Sempre tive o gosto em tornar as coisas que me rodeiam melhores. <br>
  Desde que efetuei o meu curso de Profissional de Multimédia, já <br>
  disponibilizei os  meus serviços como: </p>
  <p class="p_2_sec3"> + Estagiário em Leça de Palmeira na empresa "Wonder Dimension" 2 <br>
  meses e uma semana;<br>
  + Técnico de Multimédia desde 2015 na empresa "Tecla Virtual" em Gaia. </p>
  <p> Os meus projectos já permitiram facultar imagem corporativa a <br> 
  algumas empresas em inicialização e já conto com um reportório, embora <br>
  ainda modesto, dos meus trabalhos onde já criei: logótipos, cartazes, <br>
  flyers, capas, cartões de visita, banners...<br>
  Quando não estou a trabalhar gosto de aprender a tocar guitarra, ver <br>
  filmes, ler livros, ouvir musica, ficar informado e estar com a família. </p>
 </div>
  <!--Everything contained in this part works as intended since everything is centered and locked into place, I won't even put the images uploaded here since this part is just for reference-->
 <img class="oqueseifazer" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480694125/sparador_o_que_sei_fazer_lkypxq.png">
 <div class="posicao_horizontal2">
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img1" src="images/ilustrator.png"> </div>
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img2" src="images/photoshop.png"> </div>
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img3" src="images/dreamweaver.png"> </div>
  <div id="img2"> <img class="img4" src="images/flash.png"> </div>
 </div>
 <!---->
 <!--Here is when things get messy again once you zoom in above the 100% mark in the browser-->
 <div class="conteudo2">
 <img class="linkpdf" usemap="#linkpdfmap" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693261/link_portfolio_tnpxws.png
">
  <map name="linkpdfmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="255,35,302,84" href="portfolio/portfolio.pdf" target="_blank">
  </map>
 </div> 
</section>
<!---->

<!--Ignore the beginning of this section since it's just for reference-->
<section class="sec4">
 <h5> Propostas de Negocio </h5>
 <img class="separador" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/separador_de_titulo_preto_co4ztz.png
">
 <div class="posicao_horizontal2">
  <div id="img3"> <img class="img1" src="images/oferta_de_negocio_1.png"> </div>
  <div id="img3"> <img class="img2" src="images/oferta_de_negocio_2.png"> </div>
  <div id="img3"> <img class="img3" src="images/oferta_de_negocio_3.png"> </div>
 </div>
 <img class="pers_negocio" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/personalize_o_seu_negocio_cmv8ia.png">
<!---->
 <!--Once again this part works when you zoom out, but will move to the right once you zoom-in above the 100% mark-->
 <div class="conteudo3">
  <div class="outros_elementos">
   <p class="title_sec4"> Precisa <br>
   de outros elementos? </p>
   <p> Contacte-nos e conheça os  vários <br>
   preços e outras soluções diversas. </p>
   <p> Quer seja no complemento do seu <br>
   pack ou á parte, a Multimedia <br>
   House dispõe de um amplo serviço <br>
   de design gráfico e webdesign que <br>
   coloca ao seu dispor. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="negocios_extra">
  <div id="img4"> <img class="negocio_ilustracao" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/negocio_ilustracao_design_d4s5fi.png"> </div>
  <div id="img4"> <img class="negocio_webdesign" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/negocio_webdesign_fhe6nk.png"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </section>
<!---->
<!--Ignore the beginning since it's just for reference-->
<section class="sec5">
 <h6> Vamos Trabalhar? </h6>
 <img class="separador" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dbssny2ox/image/upload/v1480693348/separador_de_titulo_preto_co4ztz.png">
  <p class="intro_contact"> Estou actualmente dísponível para projectos freelance.<br>
 Se estiver interessado em trabalhar comigo, por favor entre em contacto através dos métodos<br>
 abaixo referidos.</p>
 <!---->
 <div id="wrapper">
 <div class="conteudo4">
  <div class="inquerito_contactos"> 
  <h2> Tem um projecto em mente ? </h2>
  <p class="par_contact"> Tire um minuto do seu tempo e responda<br>
  a um inquérito acerca do seu projecto.<br><br>
  Após responder o inquérito, entrarei em<br>
  contacto consigo o mais brevemente<br>
  possível.<br>
  </p>
  <a target="_blank" href="typeform_multimedia_house.html" class="button"> Inquérito</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="info_contactos">
  <h2> Entre em contacto comigo !</h2>
  <p class="par_contact"> Luís Henriques </p>
  <p class="par_contact"> Vila Nova de Gaia | 4400-008 </p>
  <p class="par_contact"> +351 915 974 285 </p>
  <a href="mailto:luishenriques96@gmail.com"><p class="email"> luishenriques96@gmail.com </p></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: I've tried your method but unfortunetly the content will still get out of place, and even won't stay in place when you zoom out...

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you are seeing. It looks right to me.

Comment: could you show me in what way you implemented it please?

Comment: I added it to my post. You should be able to run the snippet?